# Having two workflows in WF4.0 one being part of the other

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, flowchart

I am having a small c# 4.0 project (VS2010) with workflows.

First I had one workflow only and that worked perfect.

Now I inserted a 2nd one (and later need more).

I now got Workflow_One with many activities, and Workflow_Two with other activities.

Workflow_Two is inserted into Workflow_One as an activity.

My problem is 'I don't know how to finish or end Workflow_Two which is a part or activity of Workflow_One.

I tried to insert W_One as an activity into W_Two itself, where W_Two should end, but then VS2010 crashed and I could not open the Flowchart editor anymore...

How do I end W_Two with the flowchart editor or in the code, to continue to the parent workflow W_One again?

By the way, in my opinion it is a bug when the VS is crashing and the flowchart editor cannot be opened anymore when you insert two workflows in one each other... :-)

Please give me a hint how to tell W_Two it is finished. Thanks a lot!

Firlefanz

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found out when I get to an activity, which has no "follower", it changes automatically back to the parent workflow. I had some error which went from there back to the child workflow at once.

Best regards,
Firlefanz